# What kind of infinity is the number of different infinities?

Tags: set-theory, infinity

Cantor’s theorem states that $|\mathcal{P}(A)| > |A|$ for any set $A$.

As a special case of this, we have $|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})| > |\mathbb{N}|$. If we denote the power set of the naturals by $\mathcal{P_1}$, then $|\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P_1})| > |\mathcal{P_1}|$. Now denote the power set of $\mathcal{P_1}$ by $\mathcal{P_2}$. Applying the theorem again, we have $|\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P_1})| > |\mathcal{P_2}|$. We can repeat this process forever, with each power set, $\mathcal{P_n}$, having strictly greater cardinality than the last, $\mathcal{P_{n-1}}$.

Clearly this shows that there is an infinite number of different cardinalities of infinite sets (an infinity of infinities). My first thought is then to wonder about the nature of this infinite quantity.

I have two questions:

1. **What is the cardinality of the set of different cardinalities of infinite sets? In other words, what kind of infinity is the number of kinds of infinity? It seems like it would be countable infinity to me, as we clearly have a bijection between the naturals and these cardinalities. However, my question below may cause a problem with this argument.**
2. **In performing this iterative process on $\mathbb{N}$, are we actually covering *all* possible kinds of infinity? Can we be sure that there don’t exist any kinds of infinity that won’t at some point be generated by this process?**

A side question regarding the definition of ‘uncountable’: Does *uncountable infinity* refer to any infinity that isn’t $|\mathbb{N}|$, or is it strictly $|\mathbb{R}|$?

I hope this question makes sense and that I’m not asking something pointless or unanswerable.

Comment: Regarding your question about the definition of "uncountable": I believe it refers to any infinity that isn't $\mathbb{N}$? I actually was confused about the same thing for years, and I thought that it means the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$. But now I'm $99\%$ sure it's otherwise.

Comment: Isn't this undecidable in ZFC?

Comment: Surely there are more, and perhaps better, duplicates. I leave you with the exercise of searching for them. Those three can make quite a good stepping stone for that.

Comment: Of course I had a look for duplicates before posting, but I couldn’t find any. I’ll search further.

Comment: I'm not saying you didn't look for ones, just saying that there might be others as well...